# C# WCF Service without IIS, WSDL is not working correctly

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have to create a WCF Soap application without IIS but i am just a beginner.

I can call the method "Addiere" over my Browser but i want to see the method list over WSDL.

Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    private static ServiceHost _wcfServiceHost = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _wcfServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfTransferservice.Service1), new Uri("http://localhost:8000"));
        _wcfServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfTransferservice.IService1), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Soap");
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = _wcfServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfTransferservice.IService1), new WebHttpBinding(), "Web");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

        try
        {
            _wcfServiceHost.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("This can also be accomplished by navigating to");
            Console.WriteLine("http://localhost:8000/Web/EchoWithGet?s=Hello, world!");
            Console.WriteLine("in a web browser while this sample is running.");

            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to terminate");
            Console.ReadLine();
            _wcfServiceHost.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException cex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", cex.Message);
            _wcfServiceHost.Abort();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

IService1.cs:

```
 // HINWEIS: Mit dem Befehl "Umbenennen" im Menü "Umgestalten" können Sie den Schnittstellennamen "IService1" sowohl im Code als auch in der Konfigurationsdatei ändern.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    int Addiere(int a, int b);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    int Multipliziere(int a, int b);
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Legen Sie die Werte unten vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Metadateninformationen zu vermeiden. -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Damit in Fehlern Ausnahmedetails zum Debuggen angezeigt werden, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest. Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Ausnahmeinformationen zu vermeiden. -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        Um das Stammverzeichnis der Webanwendung beim Debuggen auszuwählen, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest.
        Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Informationen über den Webanwendungsordner zu vermeiden.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I can call the method "addiere" like this:

http://localhost:8000/Web/addiere?a=4&b=8

But how can i call WSDL to show the all methods?

Comment: by adding mex endpoint?

Comment: how to ? please say the line and file

Comment: *how to ?* well, I don't rember the code ... I just know that **mex endpoint** is what I need and then I usualy ASK GOOGLE how to do this (adding mex endpoint programmatically)... edit: very first result is ... msdn article about it...

Answer (score 0):

We need to add service metadata behavior to the service host, please refer to the below code.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9900");
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
           ServiceHost sh=new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService),uri);
            ServiceEndpoint se = sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
            se.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
            smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (smb==null)
            {
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                {
                    HttpGetEnabled = true
                };
                sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            }
            //Add MEX service endpoint to make the call from the third party possible.
            Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
            sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");
            sh.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("service is ready");
            Console.ReadLine();
            sh.Close();
```

If we want to call the service by adding service reference, we need to add the MEX endpoint. In fact, WSDL is available when the Service metadata behavior is added. The default URL is

> http://localhost:9900/?wsdl

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: thank you my friend. I solved the problem :) Your Solution is also true. Have a nice day.

Comment: Would you mind marking it as a solution?  Thanks very much. (^.^)